# Build and Sign IOS Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

How do you build and sign an iOS Xcode Project using the provision profile and certificate?

I am new to iOS so it might be easy to ask for but I searched the web but haven't found how.
I created a game using Unity 5 and built it to get the Xcode project but how can I use the certificate and the mobileprovision to sign the app ?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 0):

There is official video tutorial: [How to submit to the iOS app store](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/platform-specific/how-to-submit-to-the-ios-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a certificate and provisioning from developer account. i.e. https://developer.apple.com/ . once you create Developer certificate double click on it to install in your system. After that you can create Build and Sign from xcode.